# WP Contact Form 7 unable to send attachments

Tags: php, wordpress, attachment, contact-form-7

File attachments for a CF7 form stopped working recently. I can get the emails, but no attachments. Its for resumes, so only allowing pdf, docx, doc. Here's what's happening so far:

Form tab:

```
<label>Upload Your Resume or Portfolio (limit 2MB)</label>
[file resume filetypes:pdf|docx|doc id:resume class:form-input-text limit:1000000]
```

Mail tab, attachments field:

```
[resume]
```

- Hosting: Godaddy
- SMTP plugin: Easy WP SMTP
- Only other plugin (other than CF7): Adminimize
- wpcf7_uploads folder permissions 755
- uploads folder permissions: 755
- When I upload a file, the file doesn't appear in the temporary folder (wpcf7_uploads) at all

Fixes I've tried:

- [Attachment deleting after 60 secs](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/fix-e-mail-attachment-not-sending/)
- [Did everything on this page](https://contactform7.com/file-uploading-and-attachment/)
- [Also tried this fix](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/contact-form7-not-delivering-attachments/)
- Tried sending form with all other unnecessary plugins deactivated
- Increased file size allotment to 2mb. Sending a 6kb docx file doesn't work
- [This solution didn't work either](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/message-sent-from-form-not-receive/)
- Unable to find any errors in the server logs
- Tried allowing images, but didn't get any images back
- Tried setting both Uploads and wpcf7_uploads permissions to 777, no luck
- [Tried everything in the comments on this page](https://ideasilo.wordpress.com/2009/01/30/is-file-attachment-working-on-your-site/)

If anyone else went through this whole process and found a fix, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: It may be that your file size is larger than the limit you have set. Have you tried this [file resume filetypes:pdf|docx|doc id:resume class:form-input-text limit:5mb] ?

Comment: Yes sir, I've increased the file size allotment to 2mb. I sent a 6kb docx file and that didn't work.

Comment: Hi @madebyporter could you solve this? I'm in the same situation